# How to change the demo OS in Sony xperia tablet z

Tags: applications, sony-xperia

I have bought a sony xperia tablet z yesterday.. the showroom dint have the stock right now, so he sold me the demo piece in the display.. it is working fine, so i took it.. but after using it i understand that..it is running some kind of demo settings.. a demo video is being palyed for every 20 minutes.. if i re arrange any icons and go to another screen.. when i came back.. the icons are automatically restored to defaults..similar with volume settings.. how to remove those demo settings.. make it work like usual tablet.. thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't have a dialer app in the tablet, Ali Kabiri's answer can't be directly used. But there's a way to get into a mode where you can enter these "service codes". See [this blog post](http://www.xperiablog.net/2013/06/20/xperia-tablet-z-how-to-access-the-service-menu/) for images.

- Open the Contacts app
- Exit the initial setup if it pops up
- Go to Menu -> Settings
- Long-press the blank space in the bottom of the screen, in the middle (see images in link)
- A button called "Enter service code" should appear
- Tap the button to get a "dialer"
- Enter the code `*#*#73556673#*#*`
- Demo mode should now be deactivated!

Answer (score 1):

You can dial `*#*#sellmore#*#* or *#*#73556673#*#*` and you will not see the demo mode anymore,
but a normal retail phone doesn't have demo mode activated...
and you have to consider that demo-activated phones doesn't have warranty.

Edit:
as Onik said,
if your tablet doesn't have dialer application installed,So you have to access the service menu for inserting service commands, so you can do the following as described in the link: [Xperia Tablet Z: How to access the service menu](http://www.xperiablog.net/2013/06/20/xperia-tablet-z-how-to-access-the-service-menu/)

Comment: The tablet doesn't have a dialer, so the code can't be entered normally.

Answer (score 0):

Had no luck with the *#*#sellmore#*#* solution. Downloaded towelroot (search Google)and titanium backup (Google store) You have to enable unknown sources in the security settings to install towelroot. Also in developer options there's a toggle upper right to enable that. In that screen enable usb debugging. Install towelroot version 3 and run it. Then install titanium backup and wipe data and uninstall the "retail demo" program. You'll never have to see that dude looking at how thin the tablet is again...or readjust your brightness.